# Return one measure value for a left join in excel pivot

Tags: sql, excel, pivot, dax, powerquery

Table 1:

```
Year  Month   ID     PID

2017   02    90000   10000
2017   02    90000   10001
2017   02    90000   10002
2017   02    90000   10003
2017   02    90001   10004
```

Table 2:

```
Year  Month   ID     Amt

2017   02    90000    10
2017   02    90001    20
2017   02    90002    30
2017   02    90003    40
```

Both these tables are pulled using power query and I am doing a left join between Table 1 (Left) and Table 2 (Right) within power query itself. I created a key in both the tables which concatenates Year, Month, and ID since in power query as multiple join statements are not allowed using power query GUI and I am joining on the same key.

As a result of this join, the values I am getting is:

```
Key         ID    PID   Amt

2017029000  90000 10000   10
2017029000  90000 10001   10
2017029000  90000 10002   10
2017029000  90000 10003   10
```

And so on.

Desired Output (In Pivot):

```
 ID    PID   Amt

90000 10000   10
      10001   
      10002   
      10003
```

Since all the PID's (10000, 10001, 10002, 10003) are associated with just one ID (90000), they should show just one value i.e is 10(which looks up from table 2) so when I do filter out the PID 10000, the Amt 10 stays.

I need a left join since there are many unmatched IDs in Table 1 which are required. Also, there are similar columns to PID in the table which are required attributes.

I had earlier tried to create a relationship between both these tables in pivot but since the Table 1 consists of duplicate IDs, it wouldn't let me do the same.

Can this be done in any way using DAX or in the pivot or even from the perspective of the join?

Comment: Before joining table 1 to table 2, do a group by on table 2 and join the grouped table 2 to table 1. Not sure how this is done in PowerPivot or DAX, but is definitely possible in SQL and Power Query.

Comment: @DavidLee Both the tables are grouped by as Table1 also has some other measure columns which I have not shown for simplicity.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding your desired output, can you please edit your question and include what the result should be?

Comment: My Apologies @DavidLee. I have edited the question and put in the desired output. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how you are getting your current result. Wouldn't a left join on your key only create 1 record for PID 10000. How are you getting 4 with the same PID? I would have expected your result to look more like this: `90000 10000 = 10; 90000 10001 = 10; 90000 10002 = 10; 90000 10003 = 10;`

Comment: Yes apologies again. Updated.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, hopefully this is the last. How do you know which PID is suppose to have a value? In your example you have 10000, 10001, 10002, 10003. Is it always the one that ends in 0?

Comment: Since all the PID's (10000, 10001, 10002, 10003) are associated with just one ID (90000), they should show just one value i.e is 10(which looks up from table 2).

Comment: @DavidLee Anyway I can achieve the result? Thanks!

Comment: I would create a query that takes the min of PID given your current key and do another left join to your resulting data set with the key and min PID. You can then write an if statement and if it is not null pull in the value, if it is null leave it blank.